# Altering javascript, select check boxes

Tags: javascript, checkbox

i Have this code that select all checkboxes:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function checkAll(){
    for (var i=0;i<document.forms[0].elements.length;i++)
    {
        var e=document.forms[0].elements[i];
        if ((e.name != 'allbox') && (e.type=='checkbox'))
        {
            e.checked=document.forms[0].allbox.checked;
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="checkbox" value="on" name="allbox" onclick="checkAll();"/> Check all<br />
    <h3>Fruit</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" value="on" name="oranges" /> Oranges<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="on" name="bananas" /> Bananas<br/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

How should i alter (and how it changes the logic) JavaScript that it would work in such case:

```
<body>
    <form id="menu">
       <input type="checkbox" value="on" name="allbox" onclick="checkAll();"/> Check all<br />
    </form>
    <h3>Fruit</h3>
    <form id="select">
       <input type="checkbox" value="on" name="oranges" /> Oranges<br/>
       <input type="checkbox" value="on" name="bananas" /> Bananas<br/>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two forms in your second example.

In your JavaScript, you have an array of all forms in the document: `document.forms`

Arrays in JavaScript are zero-based, so the first form is accessed with `forms[0]`, the second with `forms[1]` and so on.

As the checkboxes in your example are on the second form, simply change your JavaScript to access the elements in the second form.

```
...
    for (var i=0;i<document.forms[1].elements.length;i++)
    {
        var e=document.forms[1].elements[i];
...
```

Or because your second form has an ID, you can access it via the ID like this:

```
...
for(var i=0;i<document.getElementById("select").elements.length;i++)
{
    var e=document.getElementById("select").elements[i];
...
```

Comment: Is it possible to refer to form[1] by id or class or something else that i could set up so that changing places it would still work?

Comment: Yes, you can add an id to the form, then access it with `document.getElementById("formId")`

Comment: And what about `if` Statement?

Answer (score 0):

You have two forms on the second page, but your script refers only to one form. You don't need to break your form into two parts (judging from your present code).

But it is possible, if you want to keep two forms. Replace `document.forms[0]` with `document.forms[1]` everywhere in your script.